# node.js setImmediate unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js

As I understand, the differences between `process.nextTick()` and `setImmediate()` are the followings:

1. callbacks scheduled by `process.nextTick()` will ALL be executed before entering the next event loop, while callbacks scheduled by `setImmediate()` will only be executed ONE per event loop.
2. Base on the characteristics stated above, it can be said that: recursive call of `process.nextTick()` can cause the program to hang up, while recursive call of `setImmediate()` will not.

Then I've written some testing code to verify the statements above, here is my code:

```
process.nextTick(function() {
    console.log('nextTick1');
});

process.nextTick(function() {
    console.log('nextTick2');
});

setImmediate(function() {
    console.log('setImmediate1');
    process.nextTick(function() {
        console.log('nextTick3');
    });
});

setImmediate(function() {
    console.log('setImmediate2');
});
```

My expected result should be

> nextTick1, nextTick2, setImmediate1, nextTick3, setImmediate2

, but what I actually got is

> nextTick1, nextTick2, setImmediate1, setImmedate2, nextTick3

Then I've run another test to study the behavior of `setImmediate()`:

```
//the following code is using express as the framework
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.end('The server is responding.');
});

app.get('/nexttick', function (req, res) {
    function callback() {
        process.nextTick(callback);
    }
    callback();
    res.end('nextTick');
});

app.get('/setimmediate', function (req, res) {
    function callback() {
        setImmediate(callback);
    }
    callback();
    res.end('setImmediate');
});
```

Step1: I accessed `http://localhost:3000/nexttick` on my browser and I got the text `nexttick`.

Step2: I accessed `http://localhost:3000/test` to test if my server is still responding to requests, and I didn't get any response, the browser kept waiting for response. This is nothing surprising because the recursive call of `process.nextTick()` had hanged up the server.

Step3: I restarted my server.

Step4: I accessed `http://localhost:3000/setimmediate` and got the text `setimmediate`

Step5: I accessed `http://localhost:3000/test` again to test if my server is still responding. And the result is as the same as Step2, I didn't get any response and the browser kept waiting for response.

This means the behavior of `process.nextTick()` and `setImmediate()` is pretty much the same but as I know they are not.

I was wondering why is this happening or have I misunderstood sth. Thank you.

P.S. I am running Node v0.12.7 under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your test results looks ok (I only refer to the first test).
Your comments "setImmediate() will only be executed ONE per event loop." is wrong, See https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg
and thats the reason you don't understand the first test results.

Basically process.nextTick will put your function at the end of the current event loop while setImmediate will put it at the next event loop.

But executing multiple setImmediate is ok and they will all go to that same next event loop.

In

```
setImmediate(function() {
    console.log('setImmediate1');
    process.nextTick(function() {
        console.log('nextTick3');
    });
});

setImmediate(function() {
    console.log('setImmediate2');
});
```

Basically you have put 2 function sthat will be invoked in next event loop, and in one of them you put another nextTick which will be invoked at the end of that same cycle but at the end of that same cycle.
So it will first invoke those 2 setImmediate and than the nextTick that was called in the first.